# Accidentally created symbolic link to a folder in that folder

Tags: symlink, recursive

I was creating a symbolic link to `folder1/folder2` in `home-folder`. But I accidentally did:

`ln -s folder1/folder2`

while in `folder2` instead of in `home-folder`. So I ended up accidentally creating a sort-of-recursive link.

Now I can't remove this link:

`rm folder1/folder2`

gives the error message `'folder1/folder2' Is a directory`.

I'm scared to go for `rmdir` or `rm -rf` because I'm not sure what will be attempted to be deleted, the link or `folder2`. This is especially an issue since `folder1/folder2` is a shared folder and I don't want to mess this up for other users on the server.

Comment: That's weird, I can't reproduce it... I tried `ln -s /tmp` while in `/tmp`, maybe that's not exactly like you? Anyway, have you tried *unlink*?

Comment: When you run `rm`, make sure you don't end with a trailing slash.  `rm folder1/folder2` should work, `rm /folder1/folder2/` would result in the error you describe.

Comment: @AndyDalton Thank you! That was precisely my error! I removed the slash and was able to delete the link!

Comment: @AndyDalton Make that an answer

Comment: `rm` is designed to _NOT_ remove directories unless you tell it to. A symlink _to_ a directory is, itself, still _not_ a directory; It's just a file that has the name of the link's target. So if `rm` refuses to remove the link, then _**STOP**_ and check your command/typing. You should not need to add the -fr flags! That indicates you mis-typed something. So good for you for not wanting to just try -fr without asking first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you have a symbolic link to a directory, if you add a trailing slash to the name then you get the directory itself, not the symlink.  As a result:

```
rm link/
```

will try to remove the directory.  What you want is to specify the link name only without a trailing slash:

```
rm link
```

That should enable you to remove the link.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove the linked file or directory Just use the below command to do the same

suppose linked file from source file

To soft link file use below command

```
ln -s /tmp/p1 /var/tmp/

/tmp/p1==>source
/var/tmp/==> Destination path where you want to create soft link
```

To remove linked file p1 use below command

```
 unlink  p1
```

It will removed automatically